# Please help me what the point I had wrong

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

[image][image]I want to find the power across each components in the circuit but the summary of power that I can find It’s not equal zero. I don’t know what do I wrong. I’ll appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: The image is very hard to read. Can you crop it or add the equations themselves to the question?

Comment: I don't like the way I_1, I_2, and I_3 are drawn in this diagram. Was that diagram given as part of the problem? It's unclear what exactly they represent.

Comment: I used my calculator for the I_1 I_2 and I_3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sources provide \$\small (P=VI)\$:

\$\small 10A: 296.43\times 10=2946.3\:W\$

\$\small 50V: 50\times 3.57=178.5\:W\$

\$\small 5A: 128.57\times 5=643.75\:W\$

Total = \$\small 3786.55\:W\$

The resistors dissipate \$\small (P=I^2R)\$:

\$\small 5\Omega : 3.57^2\times 5=63.72\:W\$

\$\small (10+5)\Omega: 8.57^2\times 15=1101.67\:W\$

\$\small 15\Omega: 6.43^2\times 15=620.17\:W\$

\$\small 20\Omega: 10^2\times 20=2000\:W\$

Total = \$\small 3786.55\:W\$

Comment: Can you explain how you got the V at 10A = 296.43 V.

Comment: I3 through 20 ohm places the bottom of 10A current source at -200V, and V1=+96.43